How do I write a block line number on the right margin using python
I have been able to read text from a pdf and separated it in blocks of 10 lines. I want to add for every page a line number on the 10th line i.e 10, 20, 30.
import PyPDF2
import pdfplumber

# Open the PDF file
with pdfplumber.open(r'C:\PyCharm Projects\AirRumi\pdfs\test.pdf') as pdf:

    # Create a PDF writer object
    writer = PyPDF2.PdfWriter()

    # Iterate through each page
    for page in pdf.pages:
        # Count pages
        pdf_file = open(r'C:\PyCharm Projects\AirRumi\pdfs\test.pdf', 'rb')
        pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(pdf_file)
        total_pages = len(pdf_reader.pages)
        print(total_pages)
        pag = pdf_reader.pages[total_pages]
        writer = PyPDF2.PdfWriter()

        # Extract text from the page
        text = page.extract_text()
        # Split the text into lines
        lines = text.split('\n')

        block_number = 10
        # Print lines in blocks of 10
        for i in range(0, len(lines), 10):
            block = lines[i:i + 10]
            print(block_number, block)
            block_number += 10


There are multiple issues with your code: (1) What is pdfplumber used for here? (2) What is the PdfWriter used for and why are you handling the last page multiple times? (3) PyPDF2 has been deprecated in favor of pypdf.

@KJ, how do I write it in the new pdf doc?

For inserting the text you would either have to insert the drawing primitives for the texts itself or rely on existing functionality. I am aware of at least PyMuPDF (https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes-text.html#how-to-insert-text) and reportlab (https://docs.reportlab.com/reportlab/userguide/ch2_graphics/#the-text-object-methods) supporting this.

Here is my out put on the terminal:
10 ['OFFICE ADMINISTRATOR/RECEPTIONIST', 'NBST MANAGEMENT LIMITED', 'CONTEXT:', 'NBST
20 ['Urban Africa Partners (UAP). UAP is an urban investment and development company that catalyses s
30 ['Administrator/Receptionist. This dynamic role plays a crucial role in ensuring our office runs smoothly and',
Now I want to write it on PDF with the number line on the right, most research  suggest I have to specify the exact point to add the text but I want something dynamic, that counts the 10 lines and inserts the number line.
