Adding Text to a long pdf
I am using PyPDF2 and reportlab, I want to insert text(a number) after every 10 lines. Using drawString(x, y, text) but the y axis has to be dynamic to be able to append the text at the end of the tenth line. How to achieve this?
import PyPDF2
import pdfplumber
import io

from reportlab.lib.units import inch
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4

# Open the PDF file
with pdfplumber.open(r'C:\PyCharm Projects\AirRumi\pdfs\test.pdf') as pdf:
  # Iterate through each page
  for page in pdf.pages:
    print(page)
    # Count pages
    pdf_file = doc = open(r'C:\PyCharm Projects\AirRumi\pdfs\test.pdf', 'rb')
    pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(pdf_file)
    total_pages = len(pdf_reader.pages)
    # print(total_pages)
    pdfWriter = PyPDF2.PdfWriter()

    for page_num in range(total_pages):
        pag = pdf_reader.pages[page_num]
        # Extract text from the page
        text = page.extract_text()
        # Split the text into lines
        lines = text.split('\n')

        block_number = 10
        # Print lines in blocks of 10
        for i in range(0, len(lines), 10):
            block = lines[i:i + 10]
            desired_line = block[- 1]  # Replace 0 with the desired line number
            # print(desired_line)
            # print(block_number, block)
            # block_number += 10
            modified_text = desired_line + str(block_number)
            block_number += 10
            print(modified_text)
            packet = io.BytesIO()
            line_num = 1
            can = canvas.Canvas(packet, pagesize=A4)
            can.drawString(580, 10 * inch - line_num * 1 * inch, "10")
            can.save()

            # move to the beginning of the StringIO buffer
            packet.seek(0)

            # create a new PDF with Reportlab
            new_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfReader(packet)

            pag.merge_page(new_pdf.pages[0])
            pdfWriter.add_page(pag)
            pdfWriter.write(r'C:\PyCharm Projects\AirRumi\pdfs\text.pdf')


With pypdf, you have to use the text extraction visitor as mentioned inside the docs: https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/extract-text.html#using-a-visitor This will give you the desired coordinates for the text and thus should allow you to place the line numbers accordingly.

This seems to be a more specific follow-up of the currently unanswered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78906364/how-do-i-write-a-block-line-number-on-the-right-margin-using-python

I am able to output the results on my  terminal but how do I write it back to the PDF?

I have also tried getting the last word from the tenth line and replaced it with the new text (last word + the number) but how do I update?
I keep getting this error
pag.update(text)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

How do I get the X,Y coordinates of the line (last word on the tenth line) ?

I have simplified your example a bit to only run on one page, but it should be easy enough to extend this to all pages. The following code uses pypdf for most of the functionality, while relying on reportlab to generate the appropriate text commands for the overlay:
import sys
from collections import defaultdict
from io import BytesIO

from pypdf import PdfReader, PdfWriter
from reportlab.pdfgen.canvas import Canvas


POSITIONS = defaultdict(lambda: sys.maxsize)
SIZES = {}


def record_line_positions(text, cm, tm, font_dict, font_size):
    x, y = tm[4], tm[5]
    # Record the x offset of the leftmost text operator.
    if POSITIONS[y] > x:
        POSITIONS[y] = x
        # Record the font size for further usage.
        # You might want to keep track of the font data as well.
        # Please note that in some cases the font size might be reported as 1.0
        # and thus might need further fixing.
        SIZES[y] = font_size



# Read the original file.
writer = PdfWriter(clone_from='file.pdf')

# Look at a specific page.
page = writer.pages[3]

# Clear the global status.
POSITIONS.clear()
SIZES.clear()

# Record the page data.
page.extract_text(visitor_text=record_line_positions)

# Add the line numbers.
for i, (y, x) in enumerate(sorted(POSITIONS.items())):
    if i % 10:
        continue
    overlay = BytesIO()
    canvas = Canvas(
        filename=overlay,
        pagesize=(page.mediabox.width, page.mediabox.height)
    )

    # As we want to set the font and font size, use the more complex approach.
    text = canvas.beginText(x=x - 20, y=page.mediabox.height - y)
    text.setFont(psfontname='Helvetica', size=SIZES[y])
    text.textLine(text=str(i))
    canvas.drawText(text)

    # Generate the overlay page.
    canvas.save()
    overlay.seek(0)

    # Add the overlay itself.
    page.merge_page(PdfReader(overlay).pages[0])

# Write the generated/updated file.
writer.write('out.pdf')

Please note that this uses the most basic approach for retrieving the text itself. Similar results can be achieved by using MuPDF (mutool convert with stext output, or PyMuPDF if you do not have to care about the AGPL implications), pdftotext or pdfminer.six, although they might require different post-processing (parsing (X)HTML, merging character level results etc.)

Great, it is adding the numbers on the left I want them on the right. Its what am trying to do. Thank @ epR8GaYuh I had given up after trying very many code combinations

I have managed to set the line numbers on the right and count lines from the top, my challenge is at the very bottom its outputting a 0(zero) which I do not want, how do I remove or avoid the zero

Just extend the modulo condition or add another continue for zero.

This has worked well on text PDFs but I have a big challenge with scanned PDFs, I have tried pytesseract but no success, any idea how to go about it on scanned PDFs (image looking like text)

Either use pytesseract with their image_to_data or image_to_boxes functions or plain Tesseract subprocess calls in hOCR mode and parse the generated hOCR file. Nevertheless, this is ouf of scope for this question.
